# Is it possible to git clone a repo inside of another repo and commit its files except for its .git folder?

Tags: git, npm

I tried to `git clone` a repo inside of another repo and the files are not included when I commit the parent repo to GitHub.

I developed some private npm packages that I use in client projects. The clients need the packages at a given version and I need a way to update these packages on my development computer (the client doesn’t). I am trying to achieve a one-way (read-only) sync from some of my private GitHub repos to local client repos.

I could then use `npm install /path/to/private/package` which would work locally and when deployed to production as the package would be part of the client repos.

I believe Git submodules are not what I am looking for as clients would need credentials to my private repos.

Possible? Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use a regular file copy of the selected version from your nested repository working tree to client's working tree?

Comment: I like the fact I (and only I) could update the packages using `git` instead of `rsync` which makes things more dangerous as I could mistype the destination path and wipe the repo.

Comment: @antlersoft Forgot to mention in my previous comment that I am looking for a way to maintain the packages over time so copying the files would require `rsync` or another sync utility. Using `git` would be very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow you're describing is essentially vendoring dependencies, and it is not a workflow that Git supports natively.  Git does support submodules, but it doesn't provide native support for vendoring the code of another repository in your own.  That would delete the history, which Git aims to preserve.

There appear to be some modules which support vendoring for node projects.  For example, there's a module called [`vendor-copy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vendor-copy) which does this and looks like it could be useful for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up using submodules (see my answer) as it looks like the only efficient option I have. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **not possible**.

Long answer, I ended up using Git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) as it’s the only option that gives me full control over package **development**, **versioning** and **distribution**.

## Development

- Using Git submodules, each client repo can include specific versions of my private packages.
- Using Git submodules, I can easily fix bugs in these private packages from within client repos and commit fixes which can easily be applied to other client projects.
- Since my private packages are hosted on private repos, only I (or authorized contributors) can commit to them.

## Versioning

- Given I don’t use the [restricted](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish) [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/) (which I love for open source projects), I have full control over package names and versioning (although, admittedly, it’s bad practice to repurpose names and versions).

## Distribution

- Using GitHub deploy keys and the SSH [config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file, I can easily configure deployment keys for client deployments.

### Here’s what that process looks like for a private package called `@sunknudsen/logger` added as a dependency to repo `foo` of client `acme`.

#### On my development computer

1. I create a SSH key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and name it `acme-foo-logger-deploy-key`.
2. I then [add a deploy key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) on GitHub using `acme-foo-logger-deploy-key.pub` and name it `acme-foo-logger` (this helps me remember where the package is deployed).
3. I then `cd` to the `foo` repo and run `git submodule add git@github.com:sunknudsen/logger.git ./@sunknudsen/logger` to add the submodule to the `foo` repo (this works without configuring the SSH config file because I am already authorized to my GitHub account using [SSH auth](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)).
4. Finally, I run `npm install @sunknudsen/logger` to add `@sunknudsen/logger` to the repo’s `package.json` and link the [local](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) package.

Note: to make the deployment procedure comprehensible, I run `cp .gitmodules .gitmodules.sample`, add `.gitmodules` to `.gitignore` and instruct dev ops in `README.md` to run `cp .gitmodules.sample .gitmodules` when they `git clone` and replace `git@github.com:sunknudsen/logger.git` by `git@sunknudsen-logger:sunknudsen/logger.git` in `.gitmodules`.

#### On acme’s server after running `git clone` and before running `npm install`

1. I upload `acme-foo-logger-deploy-key` to `~/.ssh/`.
2. I then append the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`.

```
Host sunknudsen-logger
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/acme-foo-logger-deploy-key
```

3. Finally, I run `git submodule update --init`.

Next up is the usual `npm install` stuff.

Hope this can help others!